# Upgrade problem from Vista to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade

I got the following error when upgrade Vista to Windows 7:
To upgrade Windows, the Users, Program Files, and Windows directories need to be on the same partition.

Is there a way to upgrade without reinstalling all my programs and settings, data files?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  However, if you've just moved your users folder to a different partition, you may be able to move it back by following the steps at http://www.vista4beginners.com/Move-user-files-folders-to-another-partition in reverse.  If you've moved Windows or Program Files, you're out of luck.

Good luck,